# How to lock the app from exit in react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make that the costumer will not be able to leave the app, even when he press on the home button.

My app is coded with react native, and I'm looking for solution **by the code** and not by configuration because this feature should work only for specific users...

Do you have any idea or any guide that can help me with that?

I was looking for the solution for a long time but nothing came up.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `BackHandler` events. You have to put this code in your main navigation file. When user press back button they will exit from app u can customize ur logic for that for particular user etc...

```
componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function () {
       BackHandler.exitApp();
    }.bind(this));
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress');
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer... so if I don't want the user to exitApp, should it be the same as you wrote? bc you wrote BackHandler.exitApp();

Comment: I want that the user will not be able to get out from the app in case he press on the backPress or the home button

Comment: Do you have any guide or example? im sorry but im new with react native

Comment: u can use https://github.com/asifvora/Articles-App my demo app I have implemented that are all things.